# Is there a way to sort a list by a combination of two columns in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm working on an app with a messaging function. When a user deletes a message it will populate one of two columns in the model, SenderDeleted or RecieverDeleted with the time of deletion.

The app will also have a tab that shows all deleted messages related to the user (both as a sender and recipient). I want the list of deleted messages to be sorted by both of these columns combined.

- Message 1: 9am, null //User is sender
- Message 2: null, 8am //User is recipient
- Message 3: 1pm, null //User is sender

So the user would see message 2, message 1, message 3

Comment: Can you share the code which you have written to sort on one column?

Comment: `var sorted = data.OrderBy(z => FirstColumn ?? SecondColumn).ToList()`.

Answer (score 1):

**Given:**

```
public class Message
{
    public Nullable<DateTime> SendDate {get;set;}
    public Nullable<DateTime> ReceiveDate {get;set;}
    public string Note {get;set;}
}
```

**Initialized:**

```
List<Message> messages = new List<Message>
{
    new Message { SendDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), ReceiveDate = null, Note = "Message 1: User is sender" },
    new Message { SendDate = null, ReceiveDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 8, 0, 0), Note = "Message 2: User is recipient" },
    new Message { SendDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0), ReceiveDate = null, Note = "Message 3: User is sender" },
    new Message { SendDate = null, ReceiveDate = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), Note = "Message 4: User is recipient" },
};
```

You can create a custom `Comparer` to sort the dates that are nullable, for example:

```
public class NullableDateComp : IComparer<Nullable<DateTime>>
{
    public int Compare([AllowNull] DateTime? x, [AllowNull] DateTime? y)
    {
        if (x is null && y is null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (x is null)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (y is null)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return x.Value.CompareTo(y.Value);
    }
}
```

The `Comparer` can be combined with `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` in the following way:

```
messages.OrderBy(x => x.ReceiveDate, new NullableDateComp()).ThenBy(x => x.SendDate, new NullableDateComp())
```

**Output:**

```
Message 2: User is recipient
Message 4: User is recipient
Message 1: User is sender
Message 3: User is sender
```

Comment: Consider returning `0` if _both_ dates are `null`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.icomparer.compare?view=netcore-3.1#returns `If less than 0, x is less than y.` Which makes me think your `1` and `-1` may be the wrong way around (assuming we think of `null` as the lowest value).

Comment: @mjwills Since we're considering null to be the higher value, thought I'd do it this way. Seems to pass the use cases. The comparer did need to check if both were null though.

Comment: He doesn't want to treat `null` as the largest value. If the first row was 7am rather than 9am he wants it to be first (because 7am is before 8am).